# How to share internet on Mac with WEP

Tags: macos, internet, wpa, wep

I'm using Macbook Pro 13", I want to share my internet connection via wifi, but in my sharing options, only show WPA2.
How I can share my internet with WEP ? Do I need install any packets ?
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of Internet access does your Mac have? How it is getting it? (Be as specific as you can.)

Comment: I use Ethernet to connect internet and use wifi to share internet with my iPhones
In internet sharing, wifi options, I only see WPA2 to choose. But I want to use WEP security.

Comment: And the Ethernet connects to ...? Is it a router? Or some other kind of device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)? Through 10.7, OS X's internet sharing only supported WEP encryption; in 10.8, it added WPA2 support, but for some reason dropped WPA. But the capability appears to still be there, it's just not available in the regular interface. You can expose it with this command:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :InternetSharing:SecurityType 'WEP104 SharedKey'" /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
```

(Note that you must run this as an admin user, and it'll ask for your admin password to verify.) Once you've done that, finish the setup in System Preferences -> Sharing pane -> Internet Sharing -> Wi-Fi Options -> Password as usual. But if you switch the Security mode to one of the supported options (None or WPA2 Personal), the WEP options will vanish and you'll have to rerun that command to get them back.

EDIT: There's a much easier way -- just hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key as you click on the Security pop-up menu, and the WEP options will appear on it. Credit: [Glenn Fleishman at TidBITS](http://tidbits.com/article/13158).

Comment: Note that is is a reason why they dropped it. Probably because it is not secure and you could just as well use the unencrypted option.